# Move HDDs to new hardware

Tags: raid, hard-drive

I have a proliant ML150 G6 that has storage controller problems (a Smart Array P410/Zero Memory). It has 2 HDDs in a RAID 1 (or 1+0 I do not remember). 
I have another proliant DL180 with a similar controller (a Smart Array P410/256MB) and it has 2 arrays (RAID1 of 2 HDDs and RAID5 of 3 HDDs).

The question is, may I move the 2 HDDs of the damaged server to the other one and the array is going to be recongnized without any action?

Comment: Well I have some news, I put both disks in the second server online as an additional array but both disk were not recongnized and the only option it gave me was to create a new array (with ACU and restarting the server and pressing F7 to enter ACU during POST). So I did not create nothing in oder to preserve the information.
I called HP support and told me that was because of some ID that the old server put in the disk information that only is recognized for the same model of server, and because the DL180 is a different server is correct that the HDDs are not recognized.
So, another way is to

Comment: Well, hard drives were not recognized by the second server. I put both disks as disks, because I did not want to overplay the second server Configuration Utility and saw the two discs ready to create a new arrangement, and at no time told me they were foreign disks (the same behavior rebooting and using ACU from the BIOS). For So, what I can create a new array with two drives and then access the information? Or the creation of an array clears the information of the discs? Thanks

Comment: Some time ago a did had very similar situation with two disks in raid 1. After moving them from one ML 350 G5 to new one ML350 G6 smart array controler in new server recognized that this disks where in raid 1 and restore them with no data lose and without any help from me and any config modification on smart array in G6.  But can't give you any guarantee that in your situation everything will go the same.

Answer (score 4):

Typically the RAID controller will detect the "foreign" drives and will ask if you want it to read its configuration from the drives. This will not happen automatically - you'll either be prompted during the boot process or you'll need to go into the RAID controller BIOS.

Comment: Is possible to put only one of the HDDs in the second server online, i say without having to shut down the server, and I think that the server is going to see the configuration of the HDDs and realize that is part of a RAID 1/1+0 array. My fear is to put both HDDs and for some reason lost the information. Do you think is possible?

Comment: It's possible, but not a great idea. Make sure you have backups!

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try this, shutdown down the server, put only one of the HDDs and start the system. Im going to see what reports the storage controller at POST, if say that there is something to do with the configuration utility during POST or with ACU in the operating system. I suppose when there is a risk to loose something the system tells you that the HDDs is going to be erase for example. If the situation is that nothing es possible to do, then the second chance is to put the other one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot just create a new Array and have the Information back. What you could try is getting the HP Support to tell you the RAID Metadata-Format and edit the Partition Headers by hand to make it recognized on the new Server. This is a very complicated method and I cannot recommend it.

For the future, I would stick to Software-RAID, where you get those functions for free. Been using the same array over five hardware generations. No problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of most controllers moving between the same brand, but you can only go up in version, not back. This does not work between vendors though sometimes you can do it if you are running mamdm on linux and its one of the soft types it recognizes, but usually not. Most people think it can because they use AMD/LSI/Broadcom/Avago whatever the heck they are calling themselves now. It still wont work with those if going from an IBM or a Dell version of the firmware to either of the other two.